# Bounty Rejections and Penalty Time

Tags: support, bounty

What would prevent you from placing a bounty? How long is the penalty time?

Comment: Also - what do you mean by 'bounty rejections' and 'penalty time'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties are well explained in the help center, both [in their own page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) and on [the set bounties privilege page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). It's not quite clear exactly what it is you're asking but here are some points to note:

- You can have up to three bounties active at any given time on each SE site.
- You must wait at least 24 hours before you award a bounty.
- If you have three bounties active, you can offer a new one as soon as you award one of the active ones.
- You can have each bounty active for up to seven days.
- You cannot edit the bounty message after you have posted it.
- Of course, you can add any number of comments on the question, unless the bounty brings you under [50 reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) and the question isn't yours.
- Any reputation you offer on a bounty is lost forever.

That said, this and many of your recent questions can be answered much more quickly by having a good look in the [**Help Center**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help) and in [**Meta Stack Exchange**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) (i.e. the site-wide meta, where pretty much any question you may have about the workings of the site has already been asked). I don't want to discourage you from asking questions here on Meta - believe me, we do notice and appreciate it when newcomers make an effort to figure out the rules of the game, and we're here to help you figure them out. However, more often than not you'll get your answer faster by learning to use the resources that are already there than by waiting for us to see your posts and respond ;-). For small questions like this, it is also worth checking if there's anyone in [the chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) who can help - it's also faster than Meta, and it's easier for us to figure out exactly what it is you're asking.